# Windows 10 N Pro to Windows 10 April Update

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-upgrade, windows-10-v1803

I have Windows 10 Pro N running on my PC and i want to update it to the 10 April update. When i go to Microsoft site to download the ISO, it only has 1 option, no N option like before. So can i use that installer and will it make my pc to normal Pro version (Not N version)?

Sorry for my bad english. Thanks

Comment: [use this website](https://uup.rg-adguard.net/), select Windows (Final) - 1803 (your CPU archtiecture) and select the N Pro and download the zip. Expand the zip ad run the script to download and generate the 1803 N ISO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So can i use that installer and will it make my pc to normal Pro version (Not N version)?

Microsoft has combined the different versions of Windows into a single ISO.  So that single option, is the one, you want to download.  You can also use the Upgrade Assistant or the Media Creation Tool to accomplish your task.

It will not upgrade you to Windows 10 Professional.  You would need a new license to accomplish that, but you can install the Media Feature Pack, to install the missing features that are not included in K and N editions of Windows 10.

In order to successfully upgrade to 1803, if you currently have the Media Feature Pack installed, you will have to remove it before you attempt the upgrade[.](https://superuser.com/questions/1319121/windows-10-pro-n-fails-applying-the-april-2018-update)

In order to accomplish that you should do the following:

> 1. Open Control Panel
> 2. Go to Programs and Features
> 3. On the left side, access Turn Windows Features on or off
> 4. On the new window, untick Media Features. It has a subfolder with Media Player, but you need to uninstall it completely.

Source: [Windows 10 Pro N fails applying the April 2018 update](https://superuser.com/questions/1319121/windows-10-pro-n-fails-applying-the-april-2018-update)

Comment: Note, in order to update to the newest version, you have to uninstall the Media Features first, or the update will fail. I've posted a question with answer on this, here on SuperUser.

Comment: @LPChip Is that applicable to all versions or just the newest one? I know Windows is sometimes very touchy about certain things like language packs and the Media Feature Pack.  Went ahead and linked to your question, won’t attempt to restate your excellent answer, but will still link to it.

Comment: I only had trouble updating from 1709 to 1803 and had to actually remove the Media Features to be able to install Windows 10 Pro N. So it is specific to the Windows 10 Pro N 1709 to Windows 10 Pro N 1803 update. Feel free to link to my question and answer though. :) Oh, and +1. :)

Comment: @LPChip I actually already did. Should I provide more details or is a link (the period) enough?

Comment: wow, seriously, the period is a link? lol.. No one is going to find that. xD I would change that to `More info here.` and have that to be the link.

Comment: @LPChip It adds the question to the list of linked questions.  I hate linking to other answers, when I am not prepared, to quote and cite said answer.

Comment: Ah, I hadn't noticed that section before.

Comment: So after update my pc will still on N version?

Comment: @Xubuntu121 Of course it will be.  Installing a feature update doesn’t chnage which edition you have installed.  You would have to chnage your license key for that to happen.